# pdf-merger-js throws a TypeError and Fails

Tags: node.js, npm

I have been using [pdf-merger-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-merger-js) to merge PDF files for a while now. I have used it with PDF files I have generated from HTML files and with PDF files I did not create.

Then I started getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'compressed' of undefined
```

and the merger would fail. I tried different versions of `node` with the same results. The version that has been working is `node v12.19.1`.

```
/* /path/to/project/mpdf.js */
const PDFMerger = require('pdf-merger-js');
const path = require('path');

(async () => {
    try {
        const pdfs = ['pdf1.pdf','pdf2.pdf','pdf3.pdf','pdf4.pdf','pdf5.pdf'];
        const merger = new PDFMerger();
        pdfs.map(f => path.resolve(__dirname, "subfolder", f)
        .forEach(pdf => merger.add(pdf));
                 //^^^Error occurs on this line
        await merger.save('all-merged.pdf');
    } catch( err ) {
        console.log( err );
    }
})();
```

Has any of you worked with `pdf-merger-js` and, have you encountered the above error? If so, how did you resolve the error?

**Stack Trace**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'compressed' of undefined
    at parseObject (/path/to/project/node_modules/pdfjs/lib/object/reference.js:81:15)
    at PDFReference.get [as object] (/path/to/project/node_modules/pdfjs/lib/object/reference.js:15:17)
    at new ExternalDocument (/path/to/project/node_modules/pdfjs/lib/external.js:20:42)
    at PDFMerger._addEntireDocument (/path/to/project/node_modules/pdf-merger-js/index.js:29:15)
    at PDFMerger.add (/path/to/project/node_modules/pdf-merger-js/index.js:11:12)
    at /path/to/project/app3.js:10:34
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /path/to/project/app3.js:10:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

**Update**

I have encountered another set of PDF files that are throwing a different error on the same line:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined
    at new ExternalDocument (/path/to/project/node_modules/pdfjs/lib/external.js:20:42)
    at PDFMerger._addEntireDocument (/path/to/project/node_modules/pdf-merger-js/index.js:29:15)
    at PDFMerger.add (/path/to/project/node_modules/pdf-merger-js/index.js:11:12)
    at /path/to/project/app3.js:10:34
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /path/to/project/app3.js:10:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the kind of answer I was looking for ....

If you flatten the files prior to merging them then the merging works fine. This seems to resolve the two errors I encountered.

I am using [pdf-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-flatten) just before merging as follows:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
const flattener = require('pdf-flatten');
//....
const pdfs = ['pdf1.pdf','pdf2.pdf','pdf3.pdf','pdf4.pdf','pdf5.pdf'];
for(pdf of pdfs) {
    const pdfB = await fsp.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname,"subfolder", pdf));
    const pdfFlat = await flattener.flatten(pdfB, {density: 300});
    await fsp.writeFile(path.resolve(__dirname,"subfolder", `flattened_${pdf}`), pdfFlat);
}
//....merge the flattened files:
//.... pdfs.map(p => `flattened_${p}`).....
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error whenever I used compressed PDFs for merging. Seems to be a bug in the underlying pdfjs library according to a Github [issue](https://github.com/nbesli/pdf-merger-js/issues/34) in the pdf-merger-js repository.

Comment: Thank you @Marco. That does shed some light on what's going on.